# Jest Google closure compatibility

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, google-closure-compiler

I am using jest and currently I am getting this error from datatype-expansion module.

goog.adddependency is not defined.

However, there's no problem when mocha runs the same test.

Any clues with jest and google closure?

Comment: Hey, did you find any solution?